# Sending Enum Values via TCP

Tags: c#, tcp, enums, arrays, byte

As part of a 'protocol' I have an `Enum`, which is shared across the client and server, which dictates what to do with the rest of the data

Client:

```
byte[] outStream = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes((int)Shared.CommandType.ClientJoin + "sometext");
serverStream.Write(outStream, 0, outStream.Length);
serverStream.Flush();
```

And at the server end:

```
string dataFromClient = null;
byte[] bytesFrom = new byte[1024];
NetworkStream networkStream = tcpclient.GetStream();
int bytesread = networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, bytesFrom.Length);

Byte[] commandBytes = new Byte[4];
Array.Copy(bytesFrom, commandBytes, 4);
dataFromClient = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytesFrom, 4, bytesread - 4);

//test values
int receivedcommand = BitConverter.ToInt32(commandBytes, 0);
int actualcommand = (int)Shared.CommandType.ClientJoin;
```

However, the received 'value' (1634222896 in tests) is wildly different to the actual value (0)

I'm sure I'm doing something wildly wrong, something to do with the byte array splitting, but i can't for the life of me see what

Any ideas?

(as always, if there is a better method of implementation than the one above, i am open to suggestions :) )

Comment: You're sending the enum as decimal string, not as 4 bytes.

Comment: If applicable, Have you considered using something like soap or a RESTful API to achieve this? This way you can serialize the object at one end, and deserialize at the other without too much effort.

Comment: harold is correct. Just checked. Try checking the length of byte[] outStream = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(1234567890 + "") for example to see what i mean.

Comment: @Patrik right. Also note that your code is more incorrect than just this. TCP is a streaming protocol, not packet based, so reading a block of up to 1024 neither guarantees that it all belongs to one command nor that it's even one complete command. So as a solution, I would suggest using a BinaryWriter and a BinaryReader. Then you don't have to do all the copying and BitConverting yourself.

Comment: thanks guys (specifically harold :) ) i shall look into Binary[Reader|Writer] shortly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
byte[] outStream = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes((int)Shared.CommandType.ClientJoin + "sometext");
```

becomes

```
byte[] outStream = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(0+ "sometext");

byte[] outStream = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("0sometext");
```

After receiving `commandBytes` will have bytes representation of  `{'0','s','o','m'}`

and `BitConverter.ToInt32(commandBytes, 0);` will just make an integer representation of 4 byte array,all of whose members having a non zero value (Since all are ascii text).

Comment: but how would i ensure that the Enum value is 'transmitted' as a 2byte int?